# Is there a way I can convert a[indexOfMin] = a[startIndex] into ArrayList form? I can't seem to properly do so

Tags: arrays, arraylist, selection-sort

Towards the bottom of my program I am trying to convert the selection sort algorithm that I had from an array to ArrayList. Those two lines that are producing errors were previously `a[indexOfMin] = a[startIndex];` and `a[startIndex] = min;`. I tried changing them to `a.get(indexOfMin) = a.get(startIndex);` and `a.get(startIndex) = min;` but that does not compile. Thank you for any and every bit of help!

````
class SortDouble
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;
        ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a.add(r.nextDouble());

        selectionSort(a);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.println(a.get(i));

    }

    public static void selectionSort(ArrayList<Double> a)
    {
        int n = 10;
        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < n - 1; startIndex++)
        {
            double min = a.get(startIndex);
            int indexOfMin = startIndex;
            for (int j = startIndex + 1; j < n; j++)
                if (a.get(j) < min)
                {
                    min = a.get(j);
                    indexOfMin = j; 
                }
            a.get(indexOfMin) = a.get(startIndex); // error here
            a.get(startIndex) = min; // error here
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the value at a specific index in a Arraylist, we use [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) method.
Change the two lines which were causing error to:

```
a.set(indexOfMin, a.get(startIndex));   // a[indexOfMin] = a[startIndex];
a.set(startIndex, min); // error here   // a[startIndex] = min;
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I tried using the set method, but I was using it incorrectly. Instead of having `a.set(indexOfMin, a.get(startIndex));` I just had `a.set(indexOfMin, startIndex);`, I did not know the get() method was also needed, thank you for the solution!

Comment: ah, I'm new here. I did that, although it won't show my upvote yet since I am new! Thank you for letting me know about that!